# Alpha vantage Multiple stockprices, few requests

Tags: python, rest, alpha-vantage

I'm currently working on a stockdashboard for myself using the alpha vantage REST API. My problem is that I want to get many stockprices from a list of tickers that I have, without using many requests to get all the prices from all the stocks. And also limiting the information I get from each stock to just being the stockprice for each stock. How would I query the alpha vantage api to not overload their servers with requests?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I soon found out that Alpha Vantage doesn't support this, so I created a scraper instead to use on another website to get the information with one request, it isn't really fast, but that doesn't really matter that much right now since it will be rendered with ajax on a frontend framework, but later it should be optimized.